# "thread fork" in C (ideally POSIX, but just Linux works)

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, unix, posix

Are there any libraries/pthread wrappers/`clone` arguments that would allow me to have a `tfork`--something that, just like `fork()`, allows you to continue code execution in context, as opposed to pointing to a new function to execute under a new thread.

If not, is there any simple way to write this myself?

---

Usage would be ideally just like fork but the meaning would be threadlike, so as a contrived example:

```
int main() {
        int ival = 0;
        if(tfork() == 0) {
                sleep(10);
                ival = 5;
                _exit(); // or exit or return or whatever
        } else {
                while(1) {
                        printf("ival=%d\n", ival);
                        if(ival != 0) {
                                printf("ival changed. done.\n");
                                return 0;
                        }
                        sleep(1);
                }
        }
}
```

Should output:

```
ival=0
ival=0
ival=0
ival=0
ival=0
ival=0
ival=0
ival=0
ival=0
ival=0
ival=5
ival changed. done.
```

Comment: AFAIK event fork() doesn't allow the forked process to execute in the context of the forking function, becuase

Comment: I think this would be problematic for any non-trivial usage -- two threads using the same stack would quickly hose each other.  Imagine the original thread calling one function, while the new thread calls a different function, and both threads trying to push their function's local variables onto the same stack at about the same time... somebody's local variables would get clobbered and crash.

Comment: `tfork` could make a stack as the copy of the parent stack, couldn't it?

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner: two threads on the same stack would clearly be disastrous, but allocating a second stack and copying the state would work.

Comment: It'd have to relocate any pointers on the stack that point to other locations on the stack.

Comment: You could probably do this in pthreads and make it look like 'tfork()' with some macros.

Comment: @Random832, not to mention any pointers on the heap pointing back to the stack. And any pointers on the stack pointing to relocated pointers on the heap. Etc.

Comment: @Random832: in the end, it would need to unshare at least the stack. So you'd need to turn `clone()`'s `CLONE_VM` flag into at least two separate flags, one of them for the stack.

Comment: You could in theory use sys_clone on linux to do this, but, as others have noted. it will probably lead to stack corruption as two threads use the same stack and not do what you want.

Comment: +1 interesting question, but the only answer is that it's fundamentally impossible in a shared address space.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that, because threads share the same address-space. Continuing from the same execution context (like fork() does) would mean that their stacks were in the same memory.

Of course two threads needs to have their own stacks otherwise trouble would happen.

This is why you need to specify a function to start a new thread - because the new thread has a new stack.

Comment: That's true in a technical sense, but I see no reason that a threads implementation has to expose that much of the underlying implementation.  See OpenMP as proof of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can kind of do stuff like this with [openMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP)

It's not precisely like this, but it does do the thread creation automagically, and there are mechanisms for synchronization and communication.

Answer (score 1):

Uh, this is almost what `vfork()` does on Linux, it shares the memory of the parent (but doesn't share the rest of the things that threads are supposed to share).

Since sharing the memory of the parent leads to the problems that have been talked about in the comments to your question (snd some other problems), a `vfork()` parent is actually suspended until the child drops all references to that memory, usually via `execve()` or `_exit()` (Note the underscore, `exit()` is not safe on a `vfork()` child).

The **only** things a `vfork()` child is guaranteed to be able to do safely are calling `exec*()` or `_exit()`. With a lot of knowledge and black voodoo magic, some people can do more things on a `vfork()` child on Linux, but this involves a lot of attention to detail.

So, as you can see, there are a lot of limitations to the things you can do when sharing memory and returning a la `fork()`: **there is a very good reason why thread creation usually is done by calling a function**.

Comment: In the situation I proposed, why would it be difficult to do other things provided you could properly copy/fix the stack?

Comment: @aharon: the current function needs access to the existing stack. I see two possibilities: sharing, with the problems I outlined plus some others; unsharing the stack, you'd need to modify the `clone()` syscall to allow unsharing only part of the VMAs.

Comment: Copying/fixing the stack is **not possible**. It's equivalent to the halting problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, fork() and pthread_create() are just a wrapper over clone(). You call call clone()  directly yourself to get the desired effect. For example (not actual code but very close):

```
pid = syscall(SYS_clone, (CLONE_VM | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_SYSVSEM | CLONE_PARENT), NULL, NULL, NULL );

if(-1 == pid) { 
    return -1;
}

if(pid) {
          return pid;
    } else {

     // Your new thread code goes here
   }
```

More details here:  http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone

Comment: I've looked over the man page for the actual code and can't figure it out. Can you elaborate?

Comment: when you call pthread_create you call a library function in the pthread library that uses the Linux system call clone(2) to create the new thread. pthread_create() is written according to POSIX that dictates that the new thread starts in its own function. However, clone is Linux specific and has no such limitation, so what you can do is build your own version of pthread_create using clone that will not just to a new function as desired.

The code above is pseudo code (since some flags are missing) that shows the general way to do write a pthread_create of your own.

Comment: Note this paragraph from the `clone(2)` manpage: _Another difference for sys_clone is that the child_stack argument may be zero, in which case copy-on-write semantics ensure that the child gets separate copies of stack pages when either process modifies the stack.  In this case, for correct operation, the CLONE_VM option should not be specified._

Comment: Which means that for correct operation you have to either setup a new stack, or unshare the whole address space.